# Restructuring Firebase JSON data without changing a lot of code

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

Many times when I add a new feature to my AngularFire app I need to alter the firebase data by adding a new parent to the json list. This causes me to go back and change multiple areas of my code to update how I'm iterating the json data.

For example I have the json data:

```
"userdata": {
    "user1": {
        "uniqueGeneratedKey": {
                "key1": "value1",
                "key2": "value2"                
         }
    }
 }
```

Later I decide I need to group all these uniquely generated keys so I create a parent and it looks like:

```
"userdata": {
    "user1": {
         "group1":
               "uniqueGeneratedKey": {
                    "key1": "value1",
                    "key2": "value2"
               }                
         }
    }
 }
```

Now I would have to rewrite all my functions performing CRUD operations to reflect the change. 
Is there a workflow or a way of coding to minimize the multiple changes I would need to make every time I update the database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to change the codes each time you change your database structure. So mind the scope of the project from the beginning and design your database structure in such a way that you can optimize each queries needed in your project.

You might try keeping all the CRUD operations in a single file or in a single place so that it becomes comfortable when you do the migration.

**Update**

Clarification for the comment of @nemoryoliver

Even if you maintain a backend server to do your Firebase operation, you still need to change the client application for any change as the data structure will have effect on the POJO you're using in client side. But if you're developing for mobile application, it may work well to keep a backend server to manage API and data structure versioning.

Comment: Do you mean, it's better to have a backend server to run the firebase operations? so whenever we want to change one code, we only have to change from the server?